# Minimum browser version for LESS running on client-side

Tags: css, less

What is the min version of each browser (IE, Chrome and Firefox) for [LESS](http://lesscss.org) running on client-side?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://blog.montylounge.com/2011/07/31/one-thing-about-lessjs/ it's IE6+, although they don't specify which versions of Chrome and Firefox are supported. I would assume far enough back that it shouldn't cause you any problems.